# Falling edge detector using BJT

Tags: transistors, capacitor, signal

I'm trying to build what is basically an electronic push button switch - something that would switch an led on an off with the same signal . I figured doing this would require a falling edge detector , thus , I designed this [image]

The idea behind this is that I extend the signal using the capacitor and then AND it with NOT of the signal so only a small portion of the end of the signal remains .

Something is wrong with this and I'm not able to figure out what . I don't think it's the wiring .

Also , is there any better way to make an 'electronic push button switch' ? preferably without complex ICs ?

EDIT : The power source in the end is supposed to be the other way around ;
this is what i'm trying [image]

Comment: Have you considered a MOSFET solution, here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Foc9R0dC2iI

Comment: If your referring to a toggle ON/toggle OFF action then you need feedback and a latching acting so the last state is remembered. This would be simple to do with any flip-flop. CD4013, 74HC74, 74HCT74 are just a few. Study them, because you would be building the equivalent of one to get the action you want. A transistor can convert their positive edge trigger to a negative edge. The circuit you have will do nothing as it is. V3 is backwards. R5 should be at least 10x R6, because Q1 is a discharge path for C2.

Comment: "Complex ICs", as you say, make complex circuits simple. I personally think you'd better have the complexity buried in silicon, when you can.

Comment: Your V3 is hooked up to produce -8 V instead of +8 V, for one thing.

Comment: What you probably want is a T flip flop. Maybe look into how they are made. I am too lazy to look at your circuit closely.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic approach is flawed - all you are ending up with is a short pulse instead of a long one. As several folk on here have already commented you need a circuit that has a toggling action - in other words a divider.

Consider this approach to your problem.

[image]

The first part is a switch debouncer (R1,R2 and C1). This cleans up the signal from the switch but produces a slow rise and fall.

The next part of the circuit is a pulse shaper. This is nothing more than a transistor switch or inverter circuit and  produces good rising and falling edges.

The final part is a 'divide by two' circuit made from bjts connected as a bistable. C2 and C3 are there to produce a short edge pulse input from the collector of Q1. D1 and D2 are 'steering diodes' which allow the negative edge of the input pulse to alternatively switch Q2 or Q3 off.

There are numerous articles on the interweb which explain in detail how this divider works if you wish to do some research.

Comment: Thanks for the response . My idea was to use an SR latch and connect the reset to the signal with a delayed AND gate . I figured I needed a falling edge detector to prevent any weird effects of setting and resetting at the same time . 
I got the falling edge detector to work by tinkering with the resistor values , I have put everything together but it isn't working as fast as I'd like it to - I may have to play around with the capacitors .Oh well ..

What is this circuit called though ?

Comment: Its called a (bjt) bistable multivibrator or flip-flop circuit. There are monostable and astable versions as well. Take a look at https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics-lab-24